# Meaning of "Early morning itself why are you painting the road"

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english

Source of this info is here

https://youtu.be/6NDJ-SC2_2g
Start the movie at 16: 16

Would it be right to say,

early morning only, why are you painting the road?

Instead of below

Early morning itself why are you painting the road

Comment: I don't know what would be idiomatic in Indian English. I would expect something like "It's only early morning." _Itself_ seems an odd choice of word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the characters speak would be considered non-standard in British and American English.

As noted on a sister-site https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421002/we-indians-often-say-i-finished-my-homework-today-itself-which-i-know-is-wron
In Indian dialects, the word "itself" is added to add emphasis to time expressions as in

> Yesterday itself I informed you.

Or to add focus as a topic marker, as used a few moments later:

> The front-page itself is full of accidents.

This is non-standard in British and American dialects and would be considered a mistake.  The use of "only" would also be a mistake in tests of British or American English.

The exact meaning of the man's expression would be hard to capture in Standard English dialects, for example his use of "sister" to address a young woman (to whom he is not related) but an acceptable gloss might be:

> Why are you painting the road this early in the morning?